# how to change object state value in javascript (react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, native-base, backendless

i'am using backendless api to create simple crud application. this is my table schema:

products table:

- name (string)
- price (double)
- description (text)

i use input component from native base to get the value from user. But i have problem with price, when i input price 5000 then in the database the value is not 5000 but 892350512, i think this is happen because the value from onChangeText is string and i confuse how to parseInt() in my state.

this is my code:

```
state = { data: {} }

allProduct(){
    axios.get(`${uri}/products?sortBy=created%20desc`).then(result => {
        this.setState({
            data: result.data
        })
    })
}

handleSubmit(){ 

    axios.post(`${uri}/products`, this.state.data).then(result => {
        if(result.data){
            this.allProduct,
            alert("Succes!")
        }
    })

    // alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.data))
}
```

And this is my form code to get value from user:

```
<Label style={styles.batasAtas}>Harga</Label>
<Item regular>
    <Input onChangeText={(price) => this.setState({data:{...this.state.data, price}})} keyboardType = 'numeric'/>
</Item>
```

Comment: What is `Input`, also can you log the price before `setState`?

Comment: @PritishVaidya yeah i already do alert. For ex: i input 5 on price when i submit the value is string "5"

Comment: @masdap does my answer fix that?

Comment: @Colin i already do that, but doesn't work.

Comment: SOLVED

I use this method:

create a local variable and save the onchangetext value then parse it to Number then use it to axios.post ()

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<Input onChangeText={(price) => this.setState({data:{...this.state.data, parseInt(price)}})} keyboardType='numeric'/>
```

To change the price to an integer.